# cannot open load file: subr-x

Tags: init-file

I am trying to install [ranger](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el) in emacs and
added this one to my **.emacs** file

```
(require 'ranger.el)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/ranger/")
(load 'ranger')
```

I get the following error when I open Emacs

```
File error: Cannot open load file, ranger.el
```

When I tried to [compile](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el/blob/master/tests/compile.bat) the byte code I get the following error

```
Entering directory `c:/Users/nneel/.emacs.d/lisp/ranger/'
`ranger.el:84:1:Error: Cannot open load file: subr-x`
```

I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.1.

Now what am I supposed to do to rectify this error?

Comment: Report a bug in ranger.el for using subr-x (which is not available in Emacs 24.3).

Comment: @wasamasa It's not a bug, ranger requires Emacs 24.4 or newer.  The OP just didn't use package.el…

Answer (score 3):

Ranger requires [Emacs 24.4 or newer](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el/blob/9db73d61de2e4b9caeca50f220c1f4a8a1e7cfb6/ranger.el#L9) and does simply not support Emacs 24.3 anymore.  You'll need to upgrade your Emacs version to use this extension.

Had you followed [ranger's installation instructions](https://github.com/ralesi/ranger.el#installation) Emacs' built-in package manager would have told you that ranger doesn't support your version of Emacs.

However, if you install packages manually it's **your responsibility** to check their version requirements and make sure that your Emacs version is supported.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Emacs, so did not check version compatibility. Thank you again

Comment: @NeeL Why didn't you use Emacs' package manager to install?  That's a lot easier than installing manually.